# Dynamically adjust code based on a condition

Tags: powershell

As a Powershell learner, I ran into [-f format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html).
I then thought to myself, is it possible to dynamically change code based on a condition. Take for example a mapping drive scenario:

```
$creds = Get-Credential
$share_needs_creds = $true
$drive_map = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network

if ($share_needs_creds){
     $drive_map.MapNetworkDrive('Z:', '\\server\share', $false, "$($creds.Username)", $($creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password)")
} else {
     $drive_map.MapNetworkDrive('Z:', '\\server\share', $false)
}
```

can this be re-written as follows:

```
$creds = Get-Credential
$share_needs_creds = $true
$drive_map = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network

if ($share_needs_creds){
     $condition_smart = ', "$($creds.Username)", $($creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password)"'
} else {
     $condition_smart = ''
}

$drive_map.MapNetworkDrive('Z:', '\\server\share', $false{0}) -f $condition_smart
```

Any advise is appreciated!

Comment: What would be the advantage of your second approach? It's even one line of code more than the first. ;-)

Comment: 1st - `$False` is a reserved variable name. so that is likely to fail. [*grin*] ///// 2nd - take a look at the `*-PSDrive` cmdlets AND at the idea of splatting. you can build a set of parameters - adding and removing as needed - and then pass that to a cmdlet or function.

Comment: @Olaf more lines of code can be preferred if this increases the readability of the code. There are a lot of cases where I refactor a script where the end result has more lines of code. Readability = maintainability.

Comment: @bluuf ... and ... do you feel that's the case in this case?  ;-)

Comment: @olaf nah, but any use of a COM object to tackle something for which native cmdlets available (New-PSDrive vs wscript COM) is a very bad practice which should be avoided. I was just saying that having more lines isn't bad (some people try to use oneliners for everything)

Comment: Thanks everyone for input! The purpose of this question is to see if it is a possibility. The example presented may not be the ideal candidate because, you are right, there isn't much use to doing it this way in THIS context. However, I can see some scenarios that are more suitable. @bluuf, I believe used the COM because PSDrive is not very friendly in Powershell that is lower than 5.1 (-Credential switch isn't implemented in older PS versions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not going to work - the `-f` operator returns *exactly 1 string* as output - and you need to pass a *variable* number of arguments to the parameter list of the method you're calling.

If you want to invoke a method dynamically on a `ComObject`, prepare your argument list as an array, and pass it to `.Invoke()` on the method name exposed by PowerShell's type adapter:

```
$arguments = @(
    'Z:', '\\server\share', $false
    if($share_needs_creds){
        $creds.Username, $creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password
    }
)

$drive_map.MapNetworkDrive.Invoke($arguments)
```